# Map C++ member function to C callback

Tags: c++, c, callback

In a C++ project I am using a C library to access some hardware. The C-Bindings include callbacks to notify about changes on some input pins.
The function for the callback looks like this:
`void callback(char port, uint8_t interrupt_mask, uint8_t value_mask, void *user_data)`

In my implementation I have a `SensorController` class which has a member function that should receive the callback. The member function looks like this `void SensorController::pinChanged(char port, uint8_t interrupt_mask, uint8_t value_mask, void *user_data)`.

Now I was wondering, what would be the cleanest way to avoid making the `pinChanged` function static to be able to assign the function to the callback?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `user_data` pointer to give you back a pointer to the class that owns the callback. For example.

```
void MyCallback(char port, uint8_t interrupt_mask, uint8_t value_mask, void *user_data)
{
    static_cast<Example *>(user_data)->Callback(port, interrupt_mask, value_mask);
}

class Example
{
public:

    Example()
    {
        //setup callback here - i dont know what library you're using but you should be able to pass a this pointer as user_data
        init_lib(fictionalparameter1, fictionalparameter2, this);
    }

private:

     void   Callback(char port, uint8_t interrupt_mask, uint8_t value_mask)
     {
         //callback handler here...
     }

     friend void MyCallback(char port, uint8_t interrupt_mask, uint8_t value_mask, void *user_data);
};
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That is the whole point of providing a user context pointer argument.

Comment: You should use static_cast (reinterpret_cast is implementation-defined).

Answer (score 0):

Function that receives callback can only be:

1. Ordinary function
2. Static function

Why it can't be a member class function?

It's all about pointers. Pointer to ordinary function or static function is an address to memory. <strike>Pointer to a member class function is an offset - number which should be added to object pointer (this) to access the method.</strike> [see **jv110** comment]

> In C++, member functions have an implicit parameter which points to
>   the object (the this pointer inside the member function). Normal C
>   functions can be thought of as having a different calling convention
>   from member functions, so the types of their pointers
>   (pointer-to-member-function vs pointer-to-function) are different and
>   incompatible. C++ introduces a new type of pointer, called a
>   pointer-to-member, which can be invoked only by providing an object.
>   https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#addr-of-memfn

You could use user_data in callback to access class member methods like user1320881 said.

Comment: No, only pointers to _non-function_ members are offsets. Member functions are not actual members, that's a huge waste of memory. They're like static functions, but they require an implicit "this" parameter